# How to share a MUI theme between multiple applications/projects?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes, shared-libraries

My organization is in the process of migrating to using MUI as the primary styling solution across the product suite. I tried researching online, and saw some limited conversation on what the recommended approaches are; those being a shared repository, or a microservice responsible for serving the theme. However, I could not find any details for what such implementations would look like.
I am looking for resources on how to implement a shared theme, and information on what best practices are recommended.

I read through the official MUI documentation, and did a good amount of googling to supplement the former, but could not find resources that outline how to solve the issue at hand. While the idea of a shared repository seems fairly straightforward, I am looking to get all the information possible before committing to an approach.

Comment: you could try and set up a design system  (or just the styling configuration) and distribute this via an (internal) NPM package

Comment: @Xiduzo That sounds like the optimal solution for my use case. Do you happen to know any resources for achieving this? Is it just a matter of bundling the json and the importing it where it needs to be used?

Comment: yeah, you could just create a module which exports some JSON config, or perhaps the MUI theme provider each team could wrap around their own app. Just google for something like "create and publish NPM package"

Comment: @Xiduzo that's helpful thank you. I suppose I was anticipating this to have some context-specific implementation details, but it's more straightforward than that. Will report back if I run into any unexpected technical difficulties.